# Unity, C#, Dictionary, calculating scores of teams in a match

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

ok its hard for me to wrap my head around this as it is so ill try to explane as clearly as I can what my problem is.

First of all im creating a score system for a fps game that im making.
now right now the score system uses a dubble Dictionary structure that is it has a Dictionary inside a Dictionary.

```
playerScores = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int> > ();
```

the first dictionary is creating a list of user names the 2nd dictionery is used to hold 4 keys (kills, deaths, assists, teamID)

so basicley its

```
playerScores[username][scoretype][scorevalue]
```

now it currently storing the kills and deaths of players and then is displaying them in a leader board in descending order of kills and are grouped in what team they are in and that's working all fine.

the issue I am having is trying to work out a way to calculate the teams current score for each team. and also work out what team has the highest score. I just cant get my head around it.

this here is the class that handles this data (not the leaderboard code but the scoring and stuff).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyMatchData : MonoBehaviour
{



        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int> > playerScores;
        int changeCounter = 0;
        public GameObject scoreBoard;
        Canvas scoreBoardCan;
        public float myTeamID = 0f;
        string playerNameKey = "blank";
        float myDeaths = 0f;
        float myKills = 0f;




        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
                scoreBoardCan = scoreBoard.transform.parent.GetComponent<Canvas> ();





                myDeaths = 0f;
                myKills = 0f;
        }

        void Init ()
        //init is just to make shure that we know playerscores is set b4 some one trys to use it 
        //(when ever some one calls the playerscores first they will call Init())
        {



                if (playerScores != null) {
                        return;
                }//If the player scores has been set then return out so we dont erase the scores



                playerScores = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int> > (); //must tell it that theres a new dictionery else u will get null error
                //playerScores [playerNameKey] = new Dictionary<string, int> (); // agane must tell it theres a new dictionery because this is the sub dictionery
                //a new sub dictionerey must be created for evey player. setScore() will create a new sjub dictionerey for a player if one dose not yet exsist.

        }

        void Update ()
        {

                if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Tab)) {
                        changeCounter ++;


                        //scoreBoard.SetActive ( !scoreBoard.activeSelf);
                        bool scoreBoardCanIsActive = scoreBoardCan.enabled;
                        scoreBoardCan.enabled = !scoreBoardCanIsActive;
                }

                if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.P)) {

                        ChangeScore ("sky", "kills", 1);
                }
        }

        [RPC]
        public void playerDied (bool wasBot, bool wasKilledBySomeone, string killedBy, string playerName, int playerTeam)
        {
                if (PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient) {
                        if (wasBot) {
                                Health hlscBot = GameObject.Find (playerName).GetComponent<Health> ();
                                hlscBot.GetComponent<PhotonView> ().RPC ("DeSpawn", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, "bot", playerName, playerName, playerTeam);


                        } else {
                                //player respawn stuff here
                                Debug.Log ("Host MyMatchData " + playerName);
                                Health hlsc = GameObject.Find (playerName).GetComponent<Health> ();
                                hlsc.GetComponent<PhotonView> ().RPC ("DeSpawn", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, "player", playerName, "null", -1);

                        }
                        //do Score dumping stuff here
                        if (wasKilledBySomeone == true) {
                                ChangeScore (playerName, "deaths", 1);//increase the players deaths
                                ChangeScore (killedBy, "kills", 1);//increase the killers score
                        } else {
                                ChangeScore (playerName, "deaths", 1);//increase the players deaths
                        }

                }
        }

        [RPC]
        public void firstSpawn (string userName, int teamID)
        {

                if (!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient) {
                        return;
                }


                SetScore (userName, "kills", 0);
                SetScore (userName, "deaths", 0);
                SetScore (userName, "assists", 0);
                SetScore (userName, "teamID", teamID);  

        }

        public int GetScore (string username, string scoreType)
        {
                Init ();
                if (playerScores.ContainsKey (username) == false) { //this just meens if the player name receaved has not reconised then it must not of been set yet
                        return 0;// return the player score as 0
                }
                if (playerScores [username].ContainsKey (scoreType) == false) {// at this stage we know the player name is recorded in the dictionery but we need to check if there score has been recorded yet. if not then return 0
                        return 0;// return the player score as 0
                }
                return playerScores [username] [scoreType];
        }

        public void SetScore (string username, string scoreType, int value)
        {
                Init ();
                changeCounter ++;

                if (playerScores.ContainsKey (username) == false) {//if the player has not been recorded in the dictionery yet.
                        playerScores [username] = new Dictionary<string, int> ();// Creates a new dictinerey(sub dictionery) for that player.
                }

                playerScores [username] [scoreType] = value; // the players score is now the value of value

        }

        public void ChangeScore (string username, string scoreType, int amount)
        {
                Init ();
                int currScore = GetScore (username, scoreType);
                SetScore (username, scoreType, currScore + amount); 
        }

        public string[] GetPlayerNames ()
        {
                Init ();
                return playerScores.Keys.ToArray ();
        }

        public string[] GetPlayerNames (string sortingScoreType)
        {
                Init ();

                string[] names = playerScores.Keys.ToArray (); //have to convert to array because keys dont retun a array but a list of string of keys or somthing 

                return names.OrderByDescending (n => GetScore (n, sortingScoreType)).ToArray (); //this needs to beconverted toArray because of the same issue above
                // ok so the names in this array (names) gets sorted by running the getscore function to find out who has what score. its complacated but works
                //for that to work you need using System.Linq

        }

        public int GetChangeCounter ()
        {
                return changeCounter;
        }


}
```

can any one help me work out some code to calculate the teams scores?

also there may be 2 teams or 3 or even 12 teams it just depends on how the match is set up.

also most of the comments in the code are for my understanding of the code when I wrote it.

Comment: How about 'flipping' this train of thought and creating a `Score` object which holds username, kills, deaths and any other data you want (so 1 record), and creating a `List<Score>` to hold the complete set?

Comment: 100% endorse @Melvin's suggestion. Once you have a list, LINQ will provide you with a wealth of methods for sorting, aggregating etc that will meet all your needs in terms of team scores, high scores and so forth.

Comment: im allredey using LINQ hence the using System.Linq;

Comment: The only thing you're using LINQ for is doing a single `OrderByDescending()` and two `ToArray()` calls. There is so much more that you're able to do with it, and creating that Score object will open those doors more easily to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
float myDeaths = 0f;
float myKills = 0f;
```

Unless you can achieve half death / quarter death or even 0.1569865 death, use `int`.

What I would have done something like this:

```
internal class Game
{
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; } 
    public void firstSpawn(string userName, int teamID)
    {
        if (!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
        {
            return;
        }
        Team team;
        if (Teams.Any(t => t.TeamID == teamID))
        {
            team = Teams.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TeamID == teamID);
        }
        else
        {
            team = new Team(teamID);
            Teams.Add(team);
        }            
        team.Users.Add(new User(userName));
    }


    public void playerDied(bool wasBot, bool wasKilledBySomeone, User killer, User dead, Team playerTeam)
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
        {
            if (wasBot)
            {
                Health hlscBot = GameObject.Find(dead.Name).GetComponent<Health>();
                hlscBot.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC("DeSpawn", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, "bot", dead.Name, dead.Name, playerTeam);
            }
            else
            {
                //player respawn stuff here
                Debug.Log("Host MyMatchData " + dead.Name);
                Health hlsc = GameObject.Find(playerName).GetComponent<Health>();
                hlsc.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC("DeSpawn", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, "player", dead.Name, "null", -1);
            }

            //do Score dumping stuff here
            dead.Death(); // The dead is dead, no matter if suicide or not
            if (wasKilledBySomeone)
            {
                killer.Kill();//increase the killers score
            }
         }
    }

    public bool getTheHigherTeamBy(Types type)
    {
        return Teams.Any(team => team.getTeamScore(type) == Teams.Max(t => t.getTeamScore(type)));
    }
}

internal class Team
{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } 


    public Team(int id = 0)
    {
        TeamID = id;
    }

    public int getTeamScore(Types type)
    {
        return Users.Sum(u => u.Score.getScoreFromType(type));
    }
    public string[] getPlayerNames()
    {
        return Users.Select(u => u.Name).ToArray();
    }

    public string[] GetPlayerNames(Types sortingScoreType)
    {
        return Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Score.getScoreFromType(sortingScoreType)).Select(u => u.Name).ToArray();
    }

}

public enum Types
{
    Kill,
    Death,
    Assist // Not sure about that one
}
internal class Score
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Types, int> points = new Dictionary<Types, int>();

    public Score()
    {
        // Fill the dictionnary with all the available types
        foreach (Types type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Types)))
        {
            points.Add(type, 0);
        }
    }
    public int getScoreFromType(Types type)
    {
        return points[type];
    }
    public void incrementScoreForType(Types type, int amount = 1)
    {
        points[type] += amount;
    }

}

internal class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Score Score { get; set; }

    public User(string name = "Default")
    {
        Name = name;
        Score = new Score();
    }

    public int getScoreFromType(Types type)
    {
        return Score.getScoreFromType(type);
    }

    public void changeScore(Types type, int amount)
    {
        Score.incrementScoreForType(type, amount);
    }

    public void Death()
    {
        Score.incrementScoreForType(Types.Death);
    }
    public void Kill()
    {
        Score.incrementScoreForType(Types.Kill);
    }
    public void Assist()
    {
        Score.incrementScoreForType(Types.Assist);
    }
}
```

In general, it's better to work with classes than with strings that represents fake objects: How can you take care of two players named `ARandomName` which are in the same team?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but im afraid it dose not help. You have basically just rewritten my code and not given me a ancer to my question witch is "can any one help me work out some code to calculate the teams scores" also there is a reason why the dictionary has the usernames in it and that's because its multiplayer. the host needs to calculate the data if each individual manages there own scores then the scores will get out of sync.

Comment: @user3781715 I've made a lot of changes, including the missing points from your question, is it better?